# How to know which row has been selected when having two sections of the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to program an app but I'm still a starter. When I added two sections in the tableview, I could not know which row I have selected since the same row in different sections will end up having the same row. So is there a way for me to solve this problem?[this is how my storyboard looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fcbe.png)

The function I used to get the row number is like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    var alertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    alertView.title = "Row Selected"
    alertView.show()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexPath.section` in the same way you use `indexPath.row`. Example:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 and indexPath.row == 0 {
//Do something when the first section's first row is selected
}
```